# Can I use Vue extension when developing a Chrome extension using Vue CSP mode?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, vue.js

I am using VueJS to develop for a Chrome extension. I can use the Vue extension for debugging my Vue code, when not developing for Chrome extension. However, I am not able to see the Vue extension tab when debugging my Chrome extension when inspecting in the chrome-extension with chrome developer tool. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: Be sure to have your flags set to development. Even if you have `Vue.config.debug` set to true, if your environmental variables are not set to development, say `NODE_ENV` your Vue tab will not appear

Comment: where should I set the NODE_ENV? this is chrome not running on a node environment i believe.

Comment: This apply to vueify or vue-loader. If you are using vue alone, then is not needed

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it's impossible to use vue devtools in extensions at the moment because extension pages are served over chrome-extension://

It is a known issue, link: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/120

Answer (score 0):

First,use Vue devtools in Chrome ext Development environment is enabled.

## Experience

These days I'm developing a Chrome browser plugin.I found that `__VUE_DEVTOOLS_GLOBAL_HOOK__` undefined.

Although not a big problem, but I want to solve it.I have searched a lot of information online.

#### example:

1.open `chrome-extension://<hash>/app.html`

2.set `Vue.config.devtools` to be true

3.grant Vue Devtools ext file access

**but all doesn't work.**

## Solution

As we know, `vue-devtools` is an essential piece of the Vue ecosystem, but it is currently tied to a web browser.

But now There is a package provides a standalone vue-devtools application, that can be used to debug any Vue app regardless of the environment. Now you can debug your app opened in mobile browser, safari, native script etc. not just desktop chrome or firefox.

This package name is `vue-remote-devtools`, which is a standalone electron shell to remotely debug Vue apps!

Let's have a try:

Following the `README.md` steps,

1. Install the package globally:

   `npm install -g @vue/devtools`
2. run in your terminal: `vue-devtools`

   you will see a electron app appear like this
   [image: Electron Shell]

3.inject the script tag to your Chrome Extension `.html` file.

## Warning

Due to Chrome's Content Security Policy (CSP) restrictions on plug-ins,Chrome Extension's web request may be blocked.

At this point you need to modify the Chrome Ext configuration file `manifest.js`.

```
content_security_policy: "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' http://localhost:8098; object-src 'self'"
```

Although you can copy `content_security_policy` to the corresponding file `manifest.js`, but I still hope you can find out what the CSP is:

[What is Content Security Policy (CSP)](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy)

## Finally

Connect Success！
[image]

Ref:

[vue-remote-devtools](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/master/shells/electron/README.md)

[DevTools for Chrome Extension Development.](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/issues/120)